# An administrator has installed Google Chrome on this system

Tags: google-chrome

Just a solution for this problem that chrome suddenly is installed on the system instead of user. Or at least what fixed it for me!

first backup your registry.

Open regedit and go to HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-21-***Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID{5C65F4B0-3651-4514-B207-D10CB699B14B}\LocalServer32.

first chance the (standard) to "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application(version of Google)\delegate_execute.exe"

Than chance ServerExecutable to C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application(version of Google)\delegate_execute.exe

Please note that the ". And yes it makes a difference!!!

close and restart

Comment: Is there a question here? If there is, kindly rephrase your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is on the top of the page.
Or better see the question.